# Rails server Mysql2::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm brand new to developing and ruby on rails. I'm on Windows 7, have `ruby 2.1.6`, `rails 4.2.3`, `MySQL 5.6.26`, and `Sublime Text 2 (2.0.2)` installed. I'm following an online tutorial on [lynda.com](http://lynda.com) about ruby on rails 4 essentials and ran into a problem trying to connect with my localhost:3000 rails server. I'm getting this error every time.

> Mysql2::Error (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO))

and then a whole bunch of lines of code in the command prompt I don't understand. I need some help sorting this out please!

Comment: You don't have a MySQL user named "root" with no password. This seems to be a MySQL administration issue.

Comment: In the video tutorial the instructor had us go into our app, simple_cms/confiig/database.yml and insert our password, (which I did), but our usernames were already set as root. He didn't make any changes to his username so I didn't either. As for the database field ours was set to simple_cms_development. He said we could either leave it or use a # symbol to cancel it out because it "technically didn't exist yet". I tried both to no avail.

Comment: I'm saying it's a MySQL issue, not Rails-the user you're trying to use doesn't exist as you're trying to use it, e.g., root has a password.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your_app/ config/database.yml and in username insert your MySQL username (ex. Root) and in password your MySQL password. Don't forget to fill also the field "database".

Comment: In the video tutorial the instructor had us go into our app, simple_cms/confiig/database.yml and insert our password, (which I did), but our usernames were already set as root. He didn't make any changes to his username so I didn't either. As for the database field ours was set to simple_cms_development. He said we could either leave it or use a # symbol to cancel it out because it "technically didn't exist yet". I tried both to no avail.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the responses. This is literally my first attempt at learning to program so it would be great if you could walk me through it because I'm clearly confused here but my simple_cms/config/database.yml looks like this:                                                     default: &default, adapter: mysql2, encoding: utf8, pool: 5, username: root, password: blahblahblah, host: localhost, development: <<: *default, database: simple_cms_development

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by wrong credentials. You must set database_name, user_name and password.